# How to define time/efforts in sonarqube quality gates

Tags: sonarqube

I am using Sonar server 5.6 version.

I want to set a quality gates such that efforts required to resolve all major issue should be less than or equal to 5 days (say). How can I specify such criteria as quality gates?

I can see similar condition for "Reliability Remediation Effort"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remediation costs, which are stored in minutes, are available only as totals per issue type (bug, vulnerability, code smell), not per severity.

So you would set conditions on `Technical Debt`, `Reliability Remediation Effort` and `Security Remediation Effort` ... `is greater than` your threshold.

Keep in mind that each condition is independent of the others, so if you set it to ... 60 (minutes), then you would be allowed to have 60 minutes in each category before the project failed the Quality Gate.

Comment: ok thanks for response, I am okay to have multiple condition one for each item (bug, vulnerability, code smell). Can you please tell me how to do it? I could not figure out that option.

Comment: How to define the efforts (in terms of day)? I could not find it out on the link provided.

Comment: See my expansion @AtulSureka

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, what can I do to calculate the remediation cost based on both type and severity. My use case is - I want to set the gate so that efforts required to resolve  "major" "code smells" should not be more that say 10 days. Any customization possible using some plugins or custom code ??