# How to specify the Reliability Remediation Effort?

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I want to set the Reliability Remediation Effort as 300 minutes. How can I specify this value in the SonarQube quality gate?

When I tried to set this value 300min, I get the following error:

> Unable to parse value '200min' to compare against Reliability Remediation Effort

Comment: Did you try '200'?

Comment: Thanks 200 worked but it is only covering efforts for fixing the bugs. I want to cover all issue type (bugs, vulnerability and code smell). How to set gates for the efforts for vulnerability and code smell?

Comment: See [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46175278/2662707)

Comment: I checked that, I am still not able to get how to use "Reliability Remediation Effort" field to get the total effort for (bugs, vulnerability and code smell).    To me it looks like "Reliability Remediation Effort" only covers bugs, please suggest.